# Can I read a contents at iframe by using HTML5?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, cross-domain

http://mydomain.com

```
<iframe src="http://otherdomain.com" frameborder="0" width="100%"></iframe>
```

but I caught the message from my Chrome.
Domains, protocols and ports must match.

Does anyone who can resolve it?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy

Answer (score 3):

You can't directly read the contents of iframes on other domains because it would violate the [same origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript). If you control both mydomain.com and otherdomain.com, then you can communicate between the iframe and the top-level page with the [postMessage API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.postMessage). For example, you could use `postMessage` to send the contents of the page in the iframe to the outer page.

Comment: +1 - good answer. However, *postMessage API* is limited to html5 specification. There are pretty hack'ish ways to accomplish similar techniques (like overwritting `document.domain`) on legacy browsers tho.

Comment: @jAndy - true. OP did specifically say HTML5 though :)

Comment: Thank you for ansering! should these be managed by me? mydomain.com is owned by me . but otherdomain.com is not managed by me.

Comment: If you can't modify the code that runs on otherdomain.com, then you're out of luck. If you were able to do this, then imagine what you evil things you could do; for example, when someone visits your page, you could load up their gmail inbox in an iframe and read all their messages. (or worse)

Comment: @freddiefujiwara: you can ultimately still use your *server* respectively *backend code* to sniff the *html response* from any *http server* you want to and send that back to your client.